# How to set session variable for Eval values for multiple record in database

Tags: asp.net

```
< asp:lable runat="server" ID="EmailID" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>' Height="20px"  Width="150px" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>

<%# Session["Session_TaskCode"] = DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email")%>
```

I am getting the value of Email through the `Session["Session_TaskCode"]` variable in .cs file. My problem is that I have multiple records in GridView. So, when I wanted to get the values for Email for particular records, the `Session["Session_TaskCode"]` variable takes the values of Email of the last record only.

So, how should I take the values of Email for the different records in a session variable?

Comment: At a time.. session variable hold single value... !! So For that purpose on gridview row binding event...you can assign new value to session variable... !!  But y u want to use session variable ? While it achieve normally also !!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you an use rowDataBound event of grid to take all the emails. then you can use a list to store all emails. then ad the list to the session.

```
//global declaration
List<string> emailList= new List<string>;
//Rowdatabound event
Label lblEmail= e.finfControl("lblEmail") as Lable;
emailList.add(lblEmail.Text);
session["Email"]=emailList;
```